# Solving linear equation by matrix method in Octave

Tags: octave

I was writing a code to solve linear equations by matrix method. This is my code

```
A=input('Enter the coeffecient matrix A: ');
B=input('Enter the constant matrix B (column matrix form): ');
A 
B
X=['x'; 'y'; 'z'];
R=inv(A)*B;
disp('Result');
R
```

This is what I did. But I want to get Output result to displayed in the form of
Matrix(X)=Matrix(R) so that people could directly compare the values of variables in Matrix (X) with Matrix (R) . It may very easy one but however I tried I am not getting it. How could I implement this ?

Comment: Why are python and R tagged?

Comment: I have removed the unnecessary tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually solved it by adding the code

```
for i=[1:1:3];
printf('%s = %f \n',X(i,:),R(i,:))
end
```

Answer (score 0):

How about

`prettyprint(R,["x";"y";"z"]," ")`

Or you can add a column header instead of a blank character.

This function requires the econometrics package, so if you don't have that, first do

`pkg install -forge econometrics`

`pkg load econometrics`

Comment: Hey thanks it worked , using econometrics.